# match first 2 digits of a string seperated by "."

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with `order_number` and `version_number`.

I have requirement where one of my row field is a string separated by. Eg:

```
  order_number version_number
    order_1          5.3.4
    order_2          6.2
    order_3          3.5.6
    order_4          5.3
```

Now I have an input string with only 2 digits. Eg : `5.3`, `6.2`, `3.5` etc

Now I want to write a Postgres query to select rows with input string matching only first 2 digits of the column.

It should ignore checking for matches if there is match found in first 2 digits only.

So if I give `5.3` as the input, the output should be:

```
 order_number version_number
    order_1          5.3.4
    order_4          5.3
```

Comment: why not simple `version_number like '5.3%'`?

Comment: it has to be genric. Not only with 5.3. if i give 3.5, it should fetch 3.5.6.

Comment: i used this , **SELECT order_number,firmware FROM ordertable WHERE substring(firmware from '[0-9]+\.[0-9]{1}') IN ('4.0','5.3') AND order_number = 'order_1'** and it works. Is there any better way to do this

Comment: `like '5.3%'` **will** also return `3.5.6`